# Trying to change the sorting order in listview

Tags: sorting

can someone check what's wrong with the following code?

```
private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
        {
            if (listView1.ListViewItemSorter = SortOrder.Ascending)
            {
                listView1.ListViewItemSorter = SortOrder.Descending;
            }
            else
            {
                listView1.ListViewItemSorter = SortOrder.Ascending;
            }
        }
```

Thanks guys :)

Comment: You should tag which language you are using...

Comment: Sorry  forgot, I'm using C#

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are doing single equals (=) sign which is used to assign things, not to check equality.  Try this instead:

```
private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.ListViewItemSorter == SortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            listView1.ListViewItemSorter = SortOrder.Descending;
        }
        else
        {
            listView1.ListViewItemSorter = SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
    }
```

Notice the double (==) on the `if` statement

Comment: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.IComparer' and 'System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder'
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder' to 'System.Collections.IComparer'
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder' to 'System.Collections.IComparer'